# Address Sanitizer: finding the thread causing the crash

Tags: address-sanitizer

I am writing a multithreaded program which is crashing. As you can see from the AddressSanitizer output below, AddressSanitizer prints thread ID as `T16777215` which is not matching with `pthread_self()` or `gettid()` output. Any idea what is `T16777215` ?

```
==6363== ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x600800021c98 
at pc 0x7f79415f2b95 bp 0x7f79465d66e0 sp 0x7f79465d5e88 
WRITE of size 8 at 0x600800021c98 thread T16777215

#0 0x7f79415f2b94 (/usr/lib64/libasan.so.0.0.0+0xeb94)
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Asan's thread id is simply thread's serial number:

```
u32 ThreadRegistry::CreateThread(uptr user_id, bool detached, u32 parent_tid,
                                 void *arg) {
  ...
  } else if (n_contexts_ < max_threads_) {
    // Allocate new thread context and tid.
    tid = n_contexts_++;
```

(see [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/41522da1fb978b3d17e9fbf84a0f490ab6855c57/lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_thread_registry.cc#L144) for full code).

Comment: interesting but in that case that's a useless information in the asan logs. How to one find real thread id causing the crash?

Comment: @Rahul Can you use `prctl(PR_SET_NAME, ...)` to set thread's name? Otherwise I don't think you'll be able to identify it.